# Pedestrian and bicycle route longer then car route

Tags: here-api

I'm using Here Maps API for calculating routes, most of them are for bycicle and pedestrian.
What I found very strange, is that sometimes the car-route is much smaller then the pedestrian or bicycle route.
I have one example in attachement (images route pedestrian and car).
This is from adres:
Steenweg 66, 9473 Denderleeuw, Belgium
To
Grooten Moortelhoek 17, 9473 Denderleeuw, Belgium

If I do the same in Google Maps, then it's ok...

Any suggestions …

Best regards
Bart

Code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width" />
    <script src="http://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-core.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="http://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-service.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-mapevents.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-ui.css?dp-version=1526040296" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="mapContainer" style="width: 67%; height: 100%; float:left; border: 1px solid black"></div>
    <div id="panel" style="position:absolute; width:29%; left:67%; height:97%; background:inherit; " ></div>

    <script>
      var url = window.location.toString();
      var appid = '';
      var appcode = '';
      var typeaction = '';
      var formatadres = '';
      var fromadres = '';
      var toadres = '';
      var fromlatitude = '';
      var fromlongitude = '';
      var tolatitude = '';
      var tolongitude = '';
      var minrelevance = 0;
      var routemode = '';
      // Create the parameters for the routing request:
      // var routingParameters = {
      //   // The routing mode:
      //   mode: 'fastest;car',
      //   // The start point of the route:
      //   waypoint0: fromlatlng,
      //   // The end point of the route:
      //   waypoint1: tolatlng,
      //   // To retrieve the shape of the route we choose the route
      //   representation: 'display',
      //   routeattributes : 'waypoints,summary,shape,legs',
      // };

      // omzetten van tijd in minuten en seconden
      Number.prototype.toMMSS = function () {
        return  Math.floor(this / 60)  +' min. '+ (this % 60)  + ' sec.';
      }

      //get the parameters from url
      url.match(/\?(.+)$/);
      var params = RegExp.$1;
      readUrlParameters(params);

      // Initialize the platform object:
      var platform = new H.service.Platform({
          'app_id': appid,
          'app_code': appcode
          });
      var defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers();
      var map = new H.Map(
            document.getElementById('mapContainer'),
            defaultLayers.normal.map, {
              center: {lat: 50.8121, lng: 4.2190},
              zoom: 9
        });
      var routeInstructionsContainer = document.getElementById('panel');  
      var behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(new H.mapevents.MapEvents(map));
      var ui = H.ui.UI.createDefault(map, defaultLayers);
      // Get an instance of the routing service:
      var router = platform.getRoutingService();
      // Get an instance of the geocoding service:
      var geocoder = platform.getGeocodingService();

      // CALLBACK FUNCTIONS 
      // Define a callback function to process the reverse geocoding response:
      var onShowlatlong = function(result) {
        var location = result.Response.View[0].Result[0];

        // Create an InfoBubble at the returned location with
        // the address as its contents:
        // ui.addBubble(new H.ui.InfoBubble({
        //   lat: location.Location.DisplayPosition.Latitude,
        //   lng: location.Location.DisplayPosition.Longitude
        //   }, { content: '<p class="H_ib_body">' + location.Location.Address.Label + '</p>'}));
        // Create a marker for the point:
        var adressMarker = new H.map.Marker({
            lat: location.Location.DisplayPosition.Latitude,
            lng: location.Location.DisplayPosition.Longitude
          });

        // Add the route polyline and the two markers to the map:
        map.addObjects([adressMarker]);

        map.setCenter({lat: location.Location.DisplayPosition.Latitude, lng: location.Location.DisplayPosition.Longitude});
        map.setZoom(17);  
      };

      // Define a callback function to process the geocoding response:
      var onShowadress = function(result) {
        var locations = result.Response.View[0].Result,
          position,
          marker;

        // alert(result.Response.View[0].Result[0].Relevance * 100);
        if (result.Response.View[0].Result[0].Relevance * 100 < minrelevance) {
           alert("Adres niet gevonden");
           return;
        }  
        // Add a marker for each location found
        for (i = 0;  i < locations.length; i++) {
        position = {
          lat: locations[i].Location.DisplayPosition.Latitude,
          lng: locations[i].Location.DisplayPosition.Longitude
        };

        // alert(result.Response.View[0].Result[0].MatchLevel);
        document.getElementById("fromLatitudechar").value = position.lat;
        document.getElementById("fromLongitudechar").value = position.lng;
        document.getElementById("fromRelevance").value = result.Response.View[0].Result[0].Relevance;

        marker = new H.map.Marker(position);
        map.addObject(marker);
        map.setCenter({lat: position.lat, lng: position.lng});
        map.setZoom(17);  
        }
      };

      // Define a callback function to process the calcroutlatlng:
      var onCalcRoutelatlng = function(result) {
        var route,
          routeShape,
          startPoint,
          endPoint,
          linestring;

        if (typeof result.response === 'undefined') {
          alert("Route niet gevonden");
          return;
        }
        if(result.response.route) {
        // Pick the first route from the response:
        route = result.response.route[0];
        // Pick the route's shape:
        routeShape = route.shape;
        // Create a linestring to use as a point source for the route line
        linestring = new H.geo.LineString();

        // Push all the points in the shape into the linestring:
        routeShape.forEach(function(point) {
          var parts = point.split(',');
          linestring.pushLatLngAlt(parts[0], parts[1]);
        });

        // Retrieve the mapped positions of the requested waypoints:
        startPoint = route.waypoint[0].mappedPosition;
        endPoint = route.waypoint[1].mappedPosition;

        // Create a polyline to display the route:
        var routeLine = new H.map.Polyline(linestring, {
          style: { strokeColor: 'blue', lineWidth: 5 },
          arrows: { fillColor: 'white', frequency: 5, width: 1, length: 1 }
        });

        // Create a marker for the start point:
        var startMarker = new H.map.Marker({
          lat: startPoint.latitude,
          lng: startPoint.longitude
        });

        // Create a marker for the end point:
        var endMarker = new H.map.Marker({
          lat: endPoint.latitude,
          lng: endPoint.longitude
        });

        // Add the route polyline and the two markers to the map:
        map.addObjects([routeLine, startMarker, endMarker]);

        // Set the map's viewport to make the whole route visible:
        map.setViewBounds(routeLine.getBounds());

        addWaypointsToPanel(route.waypoint);
        addManueversToPanel(route);
        addSummaryToPanel(route.summary);
        document.getElementById("distance").value = route.summary.distance;
        //alert(route.summary.distance);
        //alert(route.summary)
        // toonAfstand(route.summary);
        }
      };

      // END CALLBACK FUNCTIONS

      // functie aanroepen om taal naar het Nederlands te zetten
      switchMapLanguage(map , platform);

      switch(typeaction){
        case 'showadres': {
          if (formatadres == "latlng") {
            var reverseGeocodingParams = {
              // prox: '51.20866,3.18413',
              prox: fromadres,
              mode: 'retrieveAddresses',
              maxresults: 1
              };
            geocoder.reverseGeocode(reverseGeocodingParams, onShowlatlong, function(e) {
              alert(e);
            });
          }
          else {
            var geocodingParams = {
                searchText: fromadres
              };
            // Call the geocode method with the geocoding parameters,
            // the callback and an error callback function (called if a
            // communication error occurs):
            geocoder.geocode(geocodingParams, onShowadress, function(e) {
              alert(e);
            });
          }
          break;
        };
        case 'showpin': {
          var adressMarker = new H.map.Marker({
            lat: fromlatitude,
            lng: fromlongitude
          });

          // Add the route polyline and the two markers to the map:
          map.addObjects([adressMarker]);

          map.setCenter({lat: fromlatitude, lng: fromlongitude});
          map.setZoom(17);  
          break;
        }

        // mode=shortest;car;traffic:disabled        
        case 'calcroutelatlng': {
          var fromlatlng = 'geo!' + fromlatitude + ',' + fromlongitude;
          var tolatlng = 'geo!' + tolatitude + ',' + tolongitude;
          var routingParameters = {
            // The routing mode:
            mode: routemode,
            // The start point of the route:
            waypoint0: fromlatlng,
            // The end point of the route:
            waypoint1: tolatlng,
            // To retrieve the shape of the route we choose the route
            representation: 'display',
            routeattributes : 'waypoints,summary,shape,legs',
            maneuverattributes: 'direction,action',
            language: 'nl-nl'
          };
          router.calculateRoute(routingParameters, onCalcRoutelatlng,
            function(error) {
              alert(error.message);
            });
          break;
        }
      };

      // functie om map in het nederlands te krijgen, dit wordt aangeroepen bij het laden van de map
      function switchMapLanguage(map, platform){
        var mapTileService = platform.getMapTileService({type: 'base'}),
          // Our layer will load tiles from the HERE Map Tile API
          dutchMapLayer = mapTileService.createTileLayer(
            'maptile',
            'normal.day',
            512,
            'png8',
            {lg: 'DUT'}
            );
          map.setBaseLayer(dutchMapLayer);
          ui.removeControl('mapsettings');
          }

      function readUrlParameters (urlParameters) {
        // split up the query string and store in an
        // associative array
        var urlParameters = urlParameters.split("&");
        var queryStringList = {};

        for(var i=0;i<urlParameters.length;i++)
        {
        var tmp = urlParameters[i].split("=");
          queryStringList[tmp[0]] = unescape(tmp[1]);
        }
        appid = queryStringList["appid"];
        appcode = queryStringList["appcode"];
        typeaction = queryStringList["action"];
        formatadres = queryStringList["formatadres"];
        fromadres = queryStringList["adress1"];
        minrelevance = queryStringList["minrelevance"];
        fromlatitude = queryStringList["fromlat"];
        fromlongitude = queryStringList["fromlng"];
        tolatitude = queryStringList["tolat"];
        tolongitude = queryStringList["tolng"];
        routemode = queryStringList["routemode"];
      }

      function addWaypointsToPanel (waypoints){
        var nodeH3 = document.createElement('h5'),
          waypointLabels = [],
          i;
        nodeH3.style.marginLeft = '1%';
        for (i = 0;  i < waypoints.length; i += 1) {
          waypointLabels.push(waypoints[i].label)
        }

        nodeH3.textContent = waypointLabels.join(' - ');
        routeInstructionsContainer.innerHTML = '';
        routeInstructionsContainer.appendChild(nodeH3);
      }

      function addManueversToPanel(route){
        var nodeOL = document.createElement('ol'),
          i,
          j;

        nodeOL.style.fontSize = 'small';
        nodeOL.style.marginLeft ='2%';
        nodeOL.style.marginRight ='2%';
        nodeOL.className = 'directions';

          // Add a marker for each maneuver
        for (i = 0;  i < route.leg.length; i += 1) {
          for (j = 0;  j < route.leg[i].maneuver.length; j += 1) {
            // Get the next maneuver.
            maneuver = route.leg[i].maneuver[j];

            var li = document.createElement('li'),
              // spanArrow = document.createElement('span'),
              spanInstruction = document.createElement('span');
            // spanArrow.className = 'arrow '  + maneuver.action;
            spanInstruction.innerHTML = maneuver.instruction;
            //li.appendChild(spanArrow);
            li.appendChild(spanInstruction);

            nodeOL.appendChild(li);
          }
        }
        routeInstructionsContainer.appendChild(nodeOL);
      }

      function addSummaryToPanel(summary){
        var summaryDiv = document.createElement('div'),
        content = '';
        content += '<b>Totale afstand</b>: ' + (summary.distance / 1000)  + 'km. <br/>';
        content += '<b>Reistijd</b>: ' + summary.travelTime.toMMSS() + ' (huidig verkeer)';


        summaryDiv.style.fontSize = 'small';
        summaryDiv.style.marginLeft ='2%';
        summaryDiv.style.marginRight ='2%';
        summaryDiv.innerHTML = content;
        routeInstructionsContainer.appendChild(summaryDiv);

      }
    </script>

    <form method="post">
      <input name="fromLatitudechar" id="fromLatitudechar" type="hidden">
      <input name="fromLongitudechar" id="fromLongitudechar" type="hidden">
      <input name="toLatitudechar" id="toLatitudechar" type="hidden">
      <input name="toLongitudechar" id="toLongitudechar" type="hidden">
      <input name="fromRelevance" id="fromRelevance" type="hidden">
      <input name="toRelevance" id="toRelevance" type="hidden">
      <input name="distance" id="distance" type="hidden">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, would you please share your code?

Comment: Hi, thanks for looking into this.

Comment: Code is in the initial question.
If I go to https://wego.here.com/ and do the same routing for those adress, the walking is also longer then car.

Answer (score 0):

We checked the routing result between two addresses with route api.

And there is a restriction to turn left from Steenweg to Hertstraat. The location  lat long is 50.906072,4.054588.

We will check the restriction whether exit or not in real world and update it.

Thank you!